# Field to add employee ID in Azure AD/Office365

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

Couple of weeks back we moved from GApps to office 365. I noticed that Azure AD does not have field to enter the Employee ID. Can anyone advise is there anyway to get it.

We do not use AD Sync and we are not looking to have one.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0 if not for a specific application, you can create a placeholder app for your extension attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it does, in the user extension property.  You can use Powershell to set and expose it.

[image: Imgur]

Hope this helps........

Comment: Thanks Hannel, it helped. But is it possible to show in AzureAD GUI.

Comment: Not as far as i know, but you can always vote up a feedback or add you own. [https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?query=employee](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?query=employee)